# Is there a way to read an excel file row by row

Tags: r

I have an excel file in below format.

```
      col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   1    2     3   4
row2   5    6     7   8
row3   9    10    11  12
```

i would like read it in a below   format.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
-
-
-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can transpose and create a data.frame

```
df2 <- data.frame(col = c(t(df1)))
```

If we need only a vector then

```
c(t(df1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an .csv file, you can edit and replace the separator to "carriage return" with a notepad